# Looping through opened workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

i have managed to get a code which opens all files existing in a folder. now i want to run a macro(Called as donemovementReport) on these files one by one like as it runs on
 one i save the file then run on the next one.

The Macro donemovementreport pastes all data from these open sheets to a template. i want to save this tamplate not the opened workbook which carries the actual data.

anybody with some idea?

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()
Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim DestCell As Range
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*),*.csv*", _
        Title:="Select the workbooks to load.", MultiSelect:=True)
If IsArray(FileNames) = False Then
    If FileNames = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
For n = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FileNames(n), ReadOnly:=True)

 Next n

 'Dim i As Integer
 'i = ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges


 'For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook




 Call donemovementReport

'Next i

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the input correctly, you need to loop through ALL opened workbooks. This may be achieved using `Workbooks` collection. Use this piece of code for that:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks

    wb.AcceptAllChanges
    Call donemovementReport

Next wb
```

Modify the code between `For...Next` as you wish or provide more input.

Read more about referencing to workbooks in VBA: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/967 (the above code is item **3** of 10 listed there).