# Code not running on all opened Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[Looping through opened Workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412208/looping-through-opened-workbooks)

Its a code to which runs through all opened workbooks but here's a problem that it runs about 10 to 12 times then stops. Can anybody gimme any idea...

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()
    Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim DestCell As Range

    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*),*.csv*", _
        Title:="Select the workbooks to load.", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(FileNames) = False Then
        If FileNames = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    For n = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileNames(n), ReadOnly:=True)
    Next n

    Dim cwb As Workbook

    For Each cwb In Workbooks
        'With Application

            'cwb.AcceptAllChanges
        'End With

        Call donemovementReport

        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next cwb
 End Sub
```

Comment: why `ActiveWorkbook.Close True
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
` ? I think you can change that 2 lines into `cwb.Close True`

Comment: It's a good practice to avoid modifying or changing the members of a collection while looping through them using `for each`. You could try modifying your loop to instead use a counter and (eg) `workbooks(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Why open all workbooks in one go? Open them one by one and then close them as your work is done. For example (**Untested**)

```
 Sub OpenAllWorkbooks()
    Dim wb As Workbook, thisWb As Workbook
    Dim DestCell As Range
    Dim FileNames As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*),*.csv*", _
                Title:="Select the workbooks to load.", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(FileNames) = False Then
        If FileNames = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    For n = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileNames(n), ReadOnly:=True)

        Call donemovementReport

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next n
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Larry. That could be one of the problem. There could be 2 other reasons. `1` I don't know what "donemovementReport Sub" does. The error could be there `2` Calling `ActiveWorkbook.Close` twice may also close the workbook from where the code is being run after it closes the last workbook in that collection.

Comment: guys not gettng me! i use to open many workbooks in one time, donemovementReport picks data and paste it on another workbook(Template) opened by donemovementReport. i want to save the template on which the data is pasted but not the source file. My code is doing it nicely but its not running code on each opened file. how it could be a memory issue? i have 8gbs RAM & its an i5.

Comment: @user1960257: The above code will help you doing that. Simply change it to save the relevant file and close the other one without saving...

Comment: @user1960257 How can you open multiple workbooks at once? If it's in a thread that creates multiple instances of Excel then yes. Otherwise, you will open multiple workbooks one by one in one instance of Excel. =) Logically if you look at `File->Open Menu`, it has no option to open 10 files at once, but choose **a file to open**.. So Siddarth code is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use to cycle many files in 95% of cases - perhaps may be helpful:

```
Sub CSV_Cycling()

InputFolder = "D:\DOCUMENTS\"

    LoopFileNameExt = Dir(InputFolder & "*.csv")
    Do While LoopFileNameExt <> ""
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Workbooks.Open (InputFolder & LoopFileNameExt)
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    [..........YOUR CODE..........]
    LoopFileNameExt = Dir
    Loop 'Input Folder Files Cycling

End Sub
```

Uncomment `Application.DisplayAlerts =` strings to avoid any warnings - if required (however be careful - files will be opened using "default" options) and change source path, of course).