# Automatically open an excel file to cell A1 in all worksheets (using VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am trying to write VBA code so that whenever I open any file in excel, it automatically goes to Cell A1 in all sheets (no matter what cells were selected when it was last saved). I found something online that suggested putting the following code in my Personal .xlsb project:

```
Sub kTest()

    Dim i As Long, s() As String, a As String, n As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            a = a & .Worksheets(i).Name
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve s(1 To n)
            s(n) = .Worksheets(i).Name
            If Len(a) > 224 Then
                .Worksheets(s).Select
                .Worksheets(s(1)).Activate
                [a1].Select
                n = 0: a = "": Erase s
            End If
        Next
        If Len(a) Then
            .Worksheets(s).Select
            .Worksheets(s(1)).Activate
            [a1].Select
        End If
        Application.Goto .Worksheets(1).Range("a1")
    End With

End Sub
```

But nothing happens when I open a file. Please help!

Comment: You will need to add a WorkBook_Open event in every workbook that calls this code.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot go to Cell A1 in every sheet. But if you would like to go to Cell A1 of a single sheet you could do the following.

Create a class ExcelEvents with the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    App.Goto Wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

And in ThisWorkbook add

```
Option Explicit

Private xlApp As ExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set xlApp = New ExcelEvents
End Sub
```

Save the workbook, re-open it and the code in the workbook_open event will run and that means as soon as you open another workbook the code will goto cell A1 of sheet 1

**EDIT** If you really mean to select A1 in every single sheet you could change the code as follows

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Dim sh As Worksheet
    App.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In Wb.Worksheets
        sh.Select
        sh.Range("A1").Select
    Next
    App.Goto Wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    App.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheet.Select
        Range("A1").Select
    Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly as a stand-alone macro; however, I'm hoping to have something that automatically executes this whenever I open an excel file. I tried adding your code to ThisWorkbook excel object in my PERSONAL.xlsb in a Workbook_Open() sub, but because the PERSONAL.xlsb opens first, and then the desired file opens, there are no active workbooks when the Workbook_Open() sub runs.. Not sure if I'm making sense entirely, but basically I can't figure out how to have something run automatically in Excel every time I open ANY workbook.

Comment: Could you use this solution in conjunction with a "for each open workbook" like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14412610/6253862
Granted, this would move the selection location to workbooks you've already opened, but you could also maybe construct a temporary list of workbooks this work has been performed on.

Answer (score 0):

Using MicScoPau's loop through the worksheets
Place the following code in the ThisWorkbook module of Personal.xlsb:
You'll have to reopen excel for this to work the first time.
If your Personal.xlsb is hidden, then you will have some issues with the each sheet in activeworkbook.

```
Private WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheet.Select
        Range("A1").Select
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set app = Application
End Sub
```